# notes for slides with Apache POI

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, powerpoint

Is there a way so set notes for the slides, when I create a .pptx file with Apache POI for Java? I can only find ways to extract notes out of a presentation.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From API Doc of HSLFSlide / XSLFSlide

[setNotes()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hslf/usermodel/HSLFSlide.html#setNotes()) / [setNotes()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XSLFSlide.html#setNotes(org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.Notes))

You can add [HSLFNotes](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hslf/usermodel/HSLFNotes.html) using [Notes](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hslf/record/Notes.html) in the constructor.
For XSLFSlide use [XSLFNotes](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XSLFNotes.html)